# Exporting MySQL table to CSV using Blaze ODO library?

Tags: python, dataframe, blaze, odo

I am trying to export tables from My SQL to CSV using odo library

the code is:

```
src =f'mysql+pymysql://{MYSQL_READER_USERNAME}:%s@{MYSQL_READER_HOST}/{MYSQL_DB_NAME}' % urllib.parse.quote(f'{MYSQL_READER_PASSWORD}')

csv = odo(src+"::orders",pd.DataFrame)
print(csv)
```

but I am getting an error

```
   return Record([(c.name, meta(discover(c.type)))])
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multipledispatch/dispatcher.py", line 267, in __call__
    types = tuple([type(arg) for arg in args])
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Anyone know how to resolve this error?